# Django giving [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, django, wamp

I am developing an application with Python that parses a webpage and then downloads the images contained on the webpage. I am using WAMP for the webserver and DJango for the framework. The python script I have implemented runs as expected (downloads images to my local desktop properly) on my local computer, but when I try and run it using on the webserver with DJango and WAMP, I get the error [Errno 13] Permission  denied:'C:\Users\user123\Desktop\images'. Below is my code, any ideas what's causing the error.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os
import sys
import zipfile
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

def getdata(request):
out = r'C:\Users\user123\Desktop\images'
if request.GET.get('q'):
    #url = str(request.GET['q'])
    url = "http://google.com"
    soup = bsoup(urlopen(url))
    parsedURL = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Old Image Path: %(src)s" % image
    #Get file name
    filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
    #Get full path name if url has to be parsed
    parsedURL[2] = image["src"]
    image["src"] = '%s\%s' % (out,filename)
    print 'New Path: %s' % image["src"]
    #       print image
    outpath = os.path.join(out, filename)

    #
    if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
        urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
    else:
        urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsedURL), out) #Constructs URL from tuple (parsedURL)

    #Create HTML File and writes to it to check output (stored in same directory).
    html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
    with FileWrapper(open("output.html", "wb")) as file:
        file.write(html)

    #Create where zip file will be stored (same directory htmlparser file)
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\Users\user123\Desktop\Images.zip', 'w')

    #Path where file that will be zipped up is located
    path = 'images'

    #For each file, add it to the zip folder.
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    zip.close()
else:
        url = 'You submitted nothing!'

return HttpResponse(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your user does not seem to have write permissions for the "images" directory.
set the directory to "world writeable" and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response mawimawi, is this something I do in the WAMP/Django environment or do I just set the folder permissions individually on the windows desktop I am using?

Comment: My guess is folder permissions on windows desktop. But since I never deploy to Windows (and also not code in Windows), I can't tell for sure.

Comment: I set folder permissions to everyone, but it didn't fix the issue. I found a few leads online and I will see if they lead to anythings. Thanks again!